# WiFi puzzler - Why would WiFi be faster with Charter than with AT&T UVerse

Tags: internet, wireless-router

I consider myself fairly knowledgeable about networking having spent over 20 years in IT, but something isn't making sense and I wonder if any of you can explain it to me.

I have AT&T U-Verse and get about 15Mbps when wired.  If I connect to my wireless router I only get about 1.5Mbps.

I just got Charter internet installed and when wired I get about 60Mbps.  If I plug the same wireless router into the charter modem, I then get about 45Mbps on WiFi.  (Same router, same cable)  If I move it back over to UVerse I go back down to 1.5 to 2Mbps.

AT&T has already replaced their modem so in their eyes the problem is my router, but my tests show that's not the case.  I've also tried it with two other wireless routers and get the same results.

I'm sure there must be an explanation, but I don't know what it is.  Do you?

Comment: How are you measuring speeds?

Comment: Please list the makes and models (and perhaps if you have time, the hardware revisions and firmware versions) of all the equipment involved. My first three guesses are (1) check the Ethernet link rate and duplex settings being autonegotiated between your AP and each modem so you know there isn't a speed/duplex mismatch; (2) Make sure your AT&T U-verse 2Wire box's built-in Wi-Fi isn't on the same or overlapping channel as your AP; also make sure your AP is publishing a different network name (SSID) than the 2Wire box so you know you're really associating to your AP; (3) Avoid double-NAT.

Comment: By the way, since AT&T U-verse gateways (usually 2Wire boxes) usually include Wi-Fi AP functionality, what speed do you get when joining the U-verse gateway's Wi-Fi instead of using your own AP?